# Why key in HashMap can't be duplicated

Tags: java, dictionary, data-structures, collections

I know how hash map works. We can't use duplicate keys in Hashmap. I want to know the logic behind this used by Sun people. How it has been coded that we can't store duplicate key in HashMap.

Comment: Because then it wouldn't be a hash hap.

Comment: Try examining what a [map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_array) is... it's like a dictionary. What would happen if one key pointed to two objects?

Comment: Because it would be a multi map if you could.

Comment: @Bathsheba I have asked "What is the logic behind this Sun people used".

Answer (score 2):

It's part of the contract of the [Map interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html):

> An object that maps keys to values. A map cannot contain duplicate keys; each key can map to at most one value.

What should `Map.get(key)` return if a key has multiple values?

Comment: I know this. My question is what is the logic behind this used by Sun people.

Answer (score 1):

An `HashMap` is a data structure where is possible to save couples of key values. This data structure implements `Map`.

From [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html):

> A map cannot contain duplicate keys; each key can map to at most one value.

It is possible to retrieve directly a value using its key, so is not possible to have more values associated to the same key.

Instead is possible to have multiple keys pointing to the same value.

If you need a different data structure where multiple values are associated to the same key you can use libraries like Guava that has the concept of `Multimap`

**Note:** Using standard Map is possible to create a `Map<MyKey, List>` where you associate a list to a key. So you can also add multiple values to that key storing them in the associated list.